# How to get an Automation Account Webhook to Return Values in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webhooks, azure-automation

I'm new to ASP.NET development and the use of webhooks.
I'm using ASP.NET and an Azure Automation Account which has a webhook. I can currently execute the webhook, however I would like to have my code wait until it receives the output of the webhook. How best to do this?

ASP.NET Code:

```
public ActionResult UpdateAll()
{
    (random db calls)

    string jsonList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userEnvironmentList);

    try
    {
        string uri = "webhook_url";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        string data = jsonList;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/plain;charset=utf-8";

        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);

        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        request.BeginGetResponse((x) =>
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(x))
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return View();
}
```

PS in Automation Account:

```
param
(
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
    [object] $WebhookData
)

if ($WebhookData) {
    return "Finally this works"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call GetResponse in a synchronized context then.

Change ...

```
request.BeginGetResponse((x) =>
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(x))
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }, null);
```

To ...

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

note: GetResponse() waits till the underlying web request finishes, then it returns the result. no need to use BeginGetResponse() in your code context.

Comment: Thanks! However, the responseString I get is still the jobId of the webhook and not "Finally this works".